# Como executar função quando uma tag <p> estiver preenchida?

Tags: javascript, html

tenho uma tag `<p>` e eu quero que quando ela estiver preenchida com algum texto apareça um botão "reset", mas eu não sei como indicar que a tag está vazia/preenchida.

Comment: Queres ver se está vazia quando a página carrega ou queres saber quando muda depois de a página carregar e de forma dinâmica?

Comment: Está a usar alguma biblioteca como por exemplo o jQuery

Comment: Já tentou algum código? Tem algum exemplo para adicionar a pergunta do que já tentou fazer?

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar a resposta que solucionou sua dificuldade como `aceita`, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e veja porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

Usando [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
//Elementos
var p = document.querySelector('p');
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

//Quando clicar o botão muda texto dentro do <p> (apenas para poder mostrar)
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  p.innerHTML = input.value;
});

//Cria um observador que recebe uma função com a sua lógica
var observador = new MutationObserver(function() {
  console.log('mudou');

  if(p.innerHTML === '') {
    console.log('vazio');
  } else {
    console.log('tem alguma coisa');
  }
});

//Observa as mudanças na tag <p>, passando um objeto de configuração
observador.observe(p, {
  childList: true,
  attributes: false,
  characterData: false,
  subtree: false,
  attributeOldValue: false,
  characterDataOldValue: false
});
```

```html
<p><p>
<input>
<button>mudar</button>
```

Mais informações do [objeto de configuração](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dictdef-mutationobserverinit)

Answer (score 0):

> Verifique o conteúdo da tag

**Com conteudo** - executa a função

```js
var textoDoParagrafo = document.getElementById('qqId').textContent;

if (textoDoParagrafo!=""){
     //executa a função caso haja conteúdo na tag p cujo id é qqId
   var input = document.createElement("input");
   input.type = "reset";
   input.value = "Resetar";
   document.body.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
 <p id="qqId">Esse aqui é o conteúdo do paragrafo</p>
```

**Sem conteudo** - não executa a função

```js
var textoDoParagrafo = document.getElementById('qqId').textContent;

if (textoDoParagrafo!=""){
     //executa a função caso haja conteúdo na tag p cujo id é qqId
   var input = document.createElement("input");
   input.type = "reset";
   input.value = "Resetar";
   document.body.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
 <p id="qqId"></p>
```

**Compatibilidade textContent**

[image: compatibilidade textContent]

> A propriedade `textContent` é suportada no Internet Explorer a partir da versão 9. Em versões mais antigas do Internet Explorer, use a propriedade `innerText` para funcionalidade semelhante.
>   Existem outras propriedades e métodos em JavaScript que funcionam de maneira semelhante à propriedade `textContent`:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById ("qqId");
           
var mesnsagem = "";

mesnsagem += "\nouter text : " + elem.outerText;

mesnsagem += "\ninner HTML : " + elem.innerHTML;

mesnsagem += "\ntext Content : " + elem.textContent;

mesnsagem += "\ninner Text : " + elem.innerText;
    
console.log(mesnsagem);
```

```html
<p id="qqId">Esse aqui é o conteúdo do paragrafo</p>
```

Caso não esteja usando identificador na tag `<p>` acesse pelo indice:

```js
var textoDoParagrafo = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[2].textContent;

console.log(textoDoParagrafo);
```

```html
<p>Esse aqui é o conteúdo do paragrafo de indice 0</p>
<p>Esse aqui é o conteúdo do paragrafo de indice 1</p>
<p>Esse aqui é o conteúdo do paragrafo de indice 2</p>
<p>Esse aqui é o conteúdo do paragrafo de indice 3</p>
```

E se houver apenas uma tag `<p>` acesse pelo índice 0:

```js
var textoDoParagrafo = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent;

console.log(textoDoParagrafo);
```

```html
<p>Esse aqui é o conteúdo do paragrafo de indice 0</p>
```